# I´d like to change urls (from database)

Tags: php, mysql

Didn´t know very well what to write on the title, but this is that i need

My website stores files on the server, and each file gets its url stored in the database with other information. Like "http://website.com/folder1/file.xx"

The problem is that i have 500 files inside a folder wich are from different folders. (In the database they are, each one, on these previous folders)

So how would i do to change the /folder1/, /folder2/, /folder3/, etc
all to the same folder (the current) from the url stored in the database for each one of these files?

---

**OR MAYBE**
it would be simplier if i deleted all the files from database and re-insert them?
Do you know what php would i use for it? (List the files, and delete the respectives on database)

Comment: do your folders (the ones you want to change) have any common elements in their names, or are they just random?

Comment: More or less random. The script coulcompare the file names "file.txt" with the url in database (the end is equal) and then rectify the folder names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your loop on file link create new urls like this

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from yourtablename");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $newpath = "http://website.com/mynewfolder/";    
   $filename = basename($row['file_path']);
   $newlink  = $newpath.$filename;
   $update = mysql_query("update yourtablename set url = '".$newlink."' where id = $row['id'] ");
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my low expertee on php, how would i use this on a loop?

Comment: what is the ($row['file_path']) ? What am i supposed to replace there? the same thing of newpath var (relative url, instead of the full) ?

Comment: Besides, if yes, how are you relating the files with the database? I'me not understanding why you used id in the WHERE if the only thing that can be related is the name.... :s

Comment: $row['file_path'] is your old file path saved in database i find that path and change it to new path that is $newlink "http://website.com/mynewfolder/yourfilename.php"; and then update the url to the new url based on id

Comment: So i dont replace nothing there? - Sorry, but i still dont know what id are you talking about....

Comment: @beta, you should change where id = $row['id'] "); to be where id = ".$row['id']);